# How to debug a hard to replicate bug on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, testing, networking, null, crm

I am developing for *Resco Mobile CRM* and I am writing custom *JavaScript libraries* for the application, which calculate some fields for an `Order` and an `Order Product`.

Now I am experiencing a bug where I can't retrieve the `ID` of an `Order` from the `Order Product` (it has a lookup to the `Order`), but it happens in extremely rare cases. So far I've rewriten the code to retrieve it either from the lookup field or retrive it from a script on the `Order` where I save the `ID` in a `localStorage` variable. I've added a lot of logs as well (that's how I found that the `ID` is null).

These are the cases when the bug appeared:

1. After a synchronization between the *Resco CRM* and our CRM implementation (it usually disappears after another synchronization).
2. At the demo day, it appeared constantly and synchronizing the device again didn't helped (but the customer has very week network).

So far I've been debugging it for days and can't replicate it. I believe it is a 'networking issue' (some date is missing when the synchronization occurs), or a crash of the application (I recently found a similar crash on *Resco CRM* and Resco admited it was an error on their application, but they dismissed this one).

What can you suggest me to do in this case?

Thanks.

Best regards,
Evgeni Dyulgerov

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the answer, but it might help you to debug it.
On Chrome DevTools, you can emulate mobile devices, an inside that option you can simulate the bandwidth as you where in a terrible network.
I've never worked before with that CMS, but it seems that you're right about timing on the info retrieval. Maybe you should think about working with promises, and until the info is not fulfilled don't do a thing.

[image: GoogleDevTools]

[image]